# Polymer extend styles

Tags: css, polymer, element

**shared-styles.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/custom-style.html">

<dom-module id="shared-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      .content {
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin: 20px;
      }

      .content-center {
        display: flex;
        min-width: 100vh;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 64px);
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

**ForgotPassView.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="forgotpass-view">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
      }
    </style>

    <content-card id="contentCard"></content-card>
  </template>

  <script>
    class ForgotPassView extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'forgotpass-view';
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(ForgotPassView.is, ForgotPassView);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Hello. Tell me how to make **ForgotPassView** have own styles (:host?) And so used from shared-styles

Something like mix **:host{}** and **.content-center{}**

Answer (score 1):

You can import your custom CSS like this.

```
  <link rel="import" href="../../shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="forgotpass-view">
  <link rel="import" href="../../custom-styles.html">

<dom-module id="forgotpass-view">
<template>
  <style include="shared-styles">
    :host {
    }
  </style>

  <content-card id="contentCard">
    <paper-fab class="my-color">Test</paper-fab>
  </content-card>
</template>

<script>
  class ForgotPassView extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
      return 'forgotpass-view';
    }
  }

  window.customElements.define(ForgotPassView.is, ForgotPassView);
</script>
</dom-module>
<template>
  <style include="shared-styles">
    :host {
    }
  </style>

  <content-card id="contentCard"></content-card>
</template>

<script>
  class ForgotPassView extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
      return 'forgotpass-view';
    }
  }

  window.customElements.define(ForgotPassView.is, ForgotPassView);
</script>
```

Comment: Can I do it without inner element -> <paper-fab class="my-color">Test</paper-fab>?

Comment: sure, you can create separate component for forget pass and import in your `content-card `

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: Create component of forget pass and import that component same as you importing this component, nothing else.